No audio in citrix workspace HTML5 client on FreeBSD 14.0-p9
I am using citrix workspace via the HTML5 client (browser) on FreeBSD 14.0-p9 and do not have audio.  I thought I had audio before at some point, but it was garbled at best or just plain latent or slow.
I don't want to use the port on FreeBSD as I haven't had a good experience with that in the past, mainly, it is buggy and slow at best.  The HTML5 client is good to go out of the box, but just the audio doesn't work.
